# Gameobject is enabled automatically even when it is not enabled

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two panels P1 and P2. P1 enables a GameObject M1 and disables it later when a action is detected. P2 gets enabled after P1 gets disabled. So my problem is when P2 gets enabled, M1 gameobject  is enabled even though there is no reference of it (M1) in P2 panel.

The below code goes into P1 script. When P2 is enabled raiseRightHand gameObject automatically is enabled though there is no reference of it (M1) in P2 panel.

```
 private void OnDisable()
    {
        kinectWrapper.UnregisterForGesture(KinectGestures.Gestures.ThumbsUp, this);
        kinectWrapper.UnregisterKinectListener(this);
        raiseRightHand.SetActive(false);
        thumbsUp.SetActive(false);
        notificationPanel.SetActive(false);
        liveFeed.SetActive(false);
        liveFeed.GetComponent<GUITexture>().color = new Color(128f / 255, 128f / 255, 128f / 255, 128f / 255);
        //frontendController.SetUserFavColor(finalMaterial);
        rightHand.SetActive(false);
        canvasCursor.SetActive(false);
        bike.SetActive(false);
        for (int i = 0; i < particles.Count; i++)
        {
            gestureRecogniser.UnRegisterForGestureCallBack(i, this);
        }

        hoverToSelect.SetActive(false);

    }
```

Comment: Please add the code you are using to do this so we can help you debug it, your question as is is way too general. please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for some guidelines

Comment: Hi Navya, you have to give us more information about your code or objects in Unity. When you disable something in Unity it stops working so maybe you are disabling a gameobject trough the panel P1 (which is disabling M1) but the effect ends (so it enables M1 again) if you disable P1.

Comment: Maybe the best solution is creating a new script that handles both panels and gameobjects, so you don't depend on any panel that you are disabling